# RxSwift - Observable removing used elements

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

In my app, I have a collection of pickers. Each picker takes its values from a service.

The app layout looks something like this:

```
--------------------
-    picker 1      -
--------------------
-    add picker    -
--------------------
```

You can tap `add picker` to add more pickers, which are placed in a `UIStackView`. Each picker is backed by its `UIViewController` and has its own viewModel, while the container view controller has a viewModel as well.

After you tap `add picker` some times, you get something like this:

```
--------------------
-    picker 1      -
--------------------
-    picker 2      -
--------------------
-    picker 3      -
--------------------
```

When you tap each picker, I display a set of options to the user. The set of options comes from a web service, which is wrapped by the View Model in an `Observable<OperationType>`.

Say the service returned `option 1`, `option 2`, `option 3`, and the user picks `option 1` for the first picker, I need that when the second picker opens to only offer the user `option 2` and `option 3`.

In my main view model I have this code:

```
    var children = Variable<[ChildViewModel]>([])

    var allAvailableOperationTypes: Observable<[OperationType]> {
        return RequestManager.sharedInstance.rx
            .catalogues()
            .asObservable()
            .map { return $0.operationTypes }
        }
    }
```

I then created a new `Observable` to handle combining the last value from `allAvailableOperationTypes` and "remove" the ones already selected.

Something like:

```
var availableOperationTypes: Observable<[OperationType]> {
    return allAvailablePriceOperationTypes
        .map { (operationTypes) in
            operationTypes.filter { // keep those not used in children }
          }
    }
}
```

On the View Controller, I'm binding it to the button like:

```
    operationTypeButton.rx.tap
        .asObservable()
        .withLatestFrom(viewModel.availableOperationTypes)
        .subscribe(onNext: { [unowned self] (operationTypes) in
            self.presentPicker(forOperationTypes: operationTypes)
        })
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

If the user selects a value on the first picker, and then adds a second one, the second picker will only include the "free" options. However, the first picker will still show all the options available.

What I'd like to achieve, is for this to be hot, such that when the user taps the picker button, it only shows options he can pick.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want your UIPickerView to show all available options until another one opens up, at which point the previously active picker should collapse to the currently selected value. This means your picker viewmodels should be provided with an Observable that tells them whether they are currently active. The picker viewmodels should then `filter` your `allAvailableOperationTypes` Observable, which is what you should bind your picker to.

The main point here is that the values for your picker should be bound to an Observable as well, and not statically set. From your example it is not clear if this is already the case.

Comment: The ChildViewModel has a `Variable` that stores the current value, so I have an observable.

As for the picker, the previous pickers remain "alive". Say I start with 3 options available, the first picker picks 1, and the second 2, if I tap the first picker again, I'd like to be able to select 3.